# Jquery Mobile - Multiple Select Menu redirecting issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with Multiple Select Menu in a jquery-mobile app.

Here is my sample Code (just for demo) http://jsfiddle.net/yesvin/aSBCX/

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="sel">Select the Options </label>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="">Slect the Options</option>
         <option value="1">Prod 1</option>
        <option value="2">Prod 2</option>
        <option value="3">Prod 3</option>
        <option value="4">Prod 4</option>
        <option value="5">Prod 5</option>
        <option value="6">Prod 6</option>
        <option value="7">Prod 7</option>
        <option value="8">Prod 8</option>
        <option value="9">Prod 9</option>
        <option value="10">Prod 10</option>
        <option value="11">Prod 11</option>
        <option value="12">Prod 12</option>
        <option value="13">Prod 13</option>
        <option value="14">Prod 14</option>
        <option value="15">Prod 15</option>
        <option value="16">Prod 16</option>
        <option value="17">Prod 17</option>
        <option value="18">Prod 18</option>
        <option value="19">Prod 19</option>
        <option value="20">Prod 20</option>

    </select>
    <a href="#two" data-role="button">click</a> 
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="two">
    <div data-role="content">
    page 2
</div>
```

After changing the select menu i need to change the page by clicking the button below the menu. But what happens is, the page change is occured but it will automatically redirect to the previous page where the menu has (In Android). It works fine in desktop. How to prevent this in mobile? and what happens exactly?

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** This is same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920495/redirect-on-change-of-large-select-menu-in-jquery-mobile) 
but the solution is not working for me...

Even i tried with data-ajax="false" but no luck...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using on Android?

Comment: I am using jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css, jquery-1.8.2.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js